# IONIC/Cordova video streaming

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, rtmp

im using the latest ionic version (it's v 3.9.2),
and im trying to post a live streaming via RTMP, & i don't know how to start !?

please help me with some documentations, informations or code snippets 
sorry for my english & thanks

Comment: UP, please i need help !

Answer (score 1):

Im working on this for an app. Im using Microsoft Azure's - Azure Media Services. It has Live Streaming RTMP ingest and fragmented mp4, while i've not made much headway with the fragmented mp4 ingest - I have made some headway with RTMP but have not yet started implementing code - should be another 48 hours before I'm at that point so ill edit this post shortly.

I've managed to make it work natively in Android Studio, so that simply tells me the device supports the feature via this Git project - and needed to rule out an issue at the Azure end - which worked perfectlty:

https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster

here is the relevant Cordova dependency you'll need to do the same and you will need to do the following:

Install the dependency: https://github.com/disono/cordova-rtmp-rtsp-stream

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-rtsp-rtmp-stream
```

Mehods:

```
videoStreamer.streamRTSP('uri', [success], [failed]);
videoStreamer.streamRTMP('uri', [success], [failed]);
videoStreamer.streamRTMPAuth('uri', 'your-username', 'your-password', [success],[failed]);
```

I will update this thread with what I come up with!